# how to get all folder only in a given path in python?

Tags: python

i'm using this code to get all files in a given folder. Is there a way to get only the folders ?

```
a = os.listdir('Tools')
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
import os.path
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir('Tools') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('Tools', d))]
```

Comment: Or `next(os.walk('Tools'))[1]`.

Comment: -Ned why is it that when i try dirs = [d for d in os.listdir('Tools') if os.path.isdir(d)] in python IDLE, i only get ['Script']? My directory has this ['asunyan.gif', 'i18n', 'pynche', 'Scripts', 'versioncheck', 'webchecker'] thx :)

Answer (score 22):

**To print only the folders**

```
print os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()[1]
```

**To print only the files**

```
print os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()[2]
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: Works perfect for me. (Python 2.7, Ubuntu 16, Anaconda env)

Comment: Python 3 (for folders): print(next(os.walk(DIR_PATH))[1])

Answer (score 7):

Another method:

```
dirs = [entry.path for entry in os.scandir('Tools') if entry.is_dir()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()[1]`. Note `os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()` generates **a tuple of length 3**, where

1. `os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()[0]` is the `DIR_PATH`
2. `os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()[1]` is the **list of all folders in the `DIR_PATH`**
3. `os.walk(DIR_PATH).next()[2]` is the **list of all files in the `DIR_PATH`**

Answer (score 1):

Simple sample in python 3 for getting files and folders separated.

```py
from os.path import isdir, isfile
from os import listdir

path = "./"

# get only folders
folders = list(filter(lambda x: isdir(f"{path}\\{x}"), listdir(path)))

# get only files
files = list(filter(lambda x: isfile(f"{path}\\{x}"), listdir(path)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def ld(val):
    return next(os.walk(val))[1] # Thank you @eryksun

for fold in ld('/'):
    print(fold)
```