# Python: select only folders in a directory

Tags: python-2.7

I am wondering about a good way to isolate just the folders in any given directory. Right now I have a folder with both, folders and random files in it and I want to isolate just the folders and ignore the files, whatever they may be called. Is there a quick way to do this in python?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "Isolate?"

Comment: Say I have a folder called Scenes, inside scenes I have more folders, but also some files e.g text.txt, text.mp3. I want to ignore all the files and select just the folders. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781545/how-to-get-all-folder-only-in-a-given-path-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a duplicate question. Please check out this link and see if it serves your purpose :

[How to list only top level directories in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141291/how-to-list-only-top-level-directories-in-python)