# Strip filename from path (but only if the path points to a file)

Tags: python

The issue is actually very easy, but I'm wondering if there is a particular elegant way available to solve it I overlooked.

Consider I get a path (e.g. from the user via console input) that can point to either a directory or a file, e.g. one of the following

```
/directory1/directory2/file.txt
/directory1/directory2
```

Now I want to write code that strips away a potential filename from the end of the path, but *not* a directory name, so that in the example both paths would be reduced to `/directory1/directory2`.

- I considered `os.path.dirname`, but that always strips away the last path component, even if it is a directory
- The obvious solution is to use `os.path.isdir` or `os.path.isfile` and strip conditionally
- What I'm wondering: Is there an even shorter version available, something like `os.path.closest_dirname`?
  What probably bugs me a bit here is that `os.path.dirname` does *not* return the closest directory but instead will always return the parent directory (i.e. works more like `os.path.parentdir`)

Comment: is the filename guaranteed to have a `.format` at the end?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781545/how-to-get-all-folder-only-in-a-given-path-in-python) may help

Comment: @Prith: No, I just added it for clarity (so it's obvious it means a file). I assume the ambiguity when only looking at the name is also the reason `os.path.dirname` works as it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) that seems to do what you're looking for directly.

I don't see anything much wrong with the following though:

```
print(path if os.path.isdir(path) else os.path.dirname(path))
```

Comment: It didn't really solve the issue but it seems to be the easiest option after all, even if it might seem a tad inelegant to me as outlined in the question. If that's how Python is designed we probably have to live with it...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `parts` rather than `parents`:

```
from pathlib import Path

def foo(path):
    p = Path(path)
    return p.parts[-1]    # returns last part of path which is stripped filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work on a minimal Python distribution:

```
import os

def filefn(absfn):
  return absfn.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
```