# How to get folders list from the current dir and not subdirectories?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below snippet returns all the folders and it's sub-directories

```
for r, d, f in os.walk('/tmp/'):
    for folder in d:
        print folder
```

What I need is only the folders inside the current folder `/tmp/`

**Version**: `Python 2.7`

Comment: `os.listdir('/tmp')` ?

Comment: But I need to work with the files too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781545/how-to-get-all-folder-only-in-a-given-path-in-python does this help?

Comment: os.listdir('/tmp') display everything in the folder, even the files, which is not needed

Comment: @Silveris let me check the link

Comment: yea this one helped me os.walk('/tmp/').next()[1]

Comment: The method given here also sounds like it would work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/973489/2521423

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.walk('/tmp/').next()[1]` lists all the folders inside the current directory

```
for folder in os.walk('/tmp/').next()[1]:
    print folder
```

Comment: Or `next(os.walk('/tmp/'))[1]`. Usually, you should prefer letting the `next` function call the method for you, rather than invoking the method explicitly.

Comment: If nothing else, it's one less thing you'll have to change when making the code work with Python 3 (since the `next` method was renamed `__next__`, but the function kept the same name).